# Can I have SEO-friendly web pages with SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, seo

I'm just starting out with SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites, but most of what I've seen both in the app and in example sites look like the format of the URL is pretty fixed.

For example, most reference sites that I've seen hav their home page as 'pages/default.aspx'. I'd like to have something like '/home'. Is that possible?  If so, is it fairly simple to do or is it pretty involved?  The reference sites I saw are very good looking sites. I'm surprised they have such ugly URls.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post `http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/`

There is no OOTB features to do this. We also write custom HTTP modules for friendly URLS.

Comment: That's a helpful link.  Not an answer I was hoping for - I was hoping to manage my URL scheme within SharePoint 2010 and not in IIS.  Thank you!

Comment: @David .. We use a Custom List to Manage friendly URLs and use a IIS HTTP module to redirect.

Comment: does the HttpModule impact performance or cause other problems?  The link you provided made it sound like using modules can put your web app in an unsupported state.  Just wondering if that's a concern.

Comment: @David .. We use HTTP modules for many other purposes in our SP sites and we dont see major performance issues(with/without). Keep in mind this solution can be a pain. Luckily we have a small internet site and publishers who are patient enough to map normal urls to friendly urls and also remember to use friendly urls as links :)

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint is generally pretty good for the url. 2010 has gotten a little better to. Create your top level sites e.g. Home | Products | Pricing. Then creating a site under any of these site will give you the url like yourdomain.com/Products/Pages/whatever-my-page-is-called.aspx

Comment: That's the structure I'm trying to avoid.  When I create a new site, my pages are under `/<Site>/Pages/Home.aspx`.  I'd like it to be just `/Home`.  Sounds like OOTB that's all I can do.  Thanks!